# iPhone - Chinese text as codepoints rather than characters

Tags: ios4, cjk

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407698/iphone-how-to-load-chinese-text) describes basics of loading Chinese in iPhone apps. However, while I have no difficulty inserting characters encoded as characters, I have not figured out how to use codepoints alone. Any suggestions?

For instance, if I insert 狗不理包 into a label, it displays correctly, but if I insert the equivalent string `&#x72d7;&#x4e0d;&#x7406;&#x5305;` , all I get is the 32 ASCII characters. What do I need to do to make codepoints display as Chinese?

**EDIT**: to show codepoint-string as such, not as characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"狗不理包"];
```

I hope it helps.